# move Windows 7 OS from one SSD (128GB) drive to another (256GB)

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, ssd

I have Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit installed on a 128GB SSD drive.
Recently, I've purchased a new 500GB SSD drive and wish to move the entire OS over there, in order not to be forced to install everything all over again.
I have tried a few things I've found in various guides online, and even tried it with EaseUS TODO Backup software, but at best all I got is that when I start the PC from the new drive, I get a message to insert a bootable disk...
Any help in this matter will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Your SSD manufacturer sometimes has tools for this provided with the SSD, or it can be downloaded from their website. Check it out.

If not, I can recommend this great tool by Paragon:

https://www.paragon-software.com/no/home/migrate-OS-to-SSD/

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. At the very least you should provide more than just/at least a link, for example some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.